# drupal 7 How can I get cron jobs to run automatically

Tags: php, ubuntu, drupal, drupal-7, cron

I have installed the elysia cron module and setup the cron job.
So far I'm running cron jobs mannually. And it is quite time consuming because I have other things to do than run cron every 2 hours. I read the handbooks on cron configurations, but didn't get much, since I'm not a PHP literate person.

How can I make my drupal run cron automatically??? So that I don't have to come back to my site every 2 hours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the crontab. Usually this can be accessed on your server by running `crontab -e` in the shell and then adding an entry to specify how frequently to update your site. For example,

```
0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://{your_drupal_server}/cron.php
```

would run every hour. Replace {your_drupal_server} with the url of your server. The command assumes you have wget installed as well.

These sites may be helpful:

- Drupal's page on setting up crontab -
  https://www.drupal.org/node/23714
- Wiki's page on cron -
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron